# jQuery. Анимация в меню перехода по странице

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3

Доброго дня всем!
Столкнулся с такой задачей : 
Есть сайт-лендинг, есть меню и несколько блоков контента.

Меню (во всю ширину страницы) представляет из себя логотип (статичен) -> некоторый объект, пункты меню (иконки). Суть такова, что при скролле по блокам ниже должны плавно и анимированно подсвечиваться пункты меню, а объект перемещался бы от первого пункта к текущему (в зависимости от контента), соответственно предыдущая иконка думаю должна оставаться активной показывая "пройденный путь". Но дело в том, что объект должен перемещаться к следующему пункту меню в зависимости от количества контента в блоке.

Может кто-то реализовывал что-то подобное? Буду очень благодарен за любые наводки по вопросу.

Comment: держи https://codepen.io/eneox/pen/daEze?q=scroll+menu&limit=all&type=type-pens

Comment: Оу, спасибо, но не совсем то что надо(